# iCaldendar - How will PHP apply the timezone, start, end time correctly on ics file?

Tags: php, macos, outlook, icalendar, vcalendar

Why the following `startTime` and `endTime` in Outlook and Mac calendar not inserting with exact time as below?

Input:

```
$timezone = 'Europe/Luxembourg';
$startTime =  "2016-11-03 18:00:00";        
$endTime =  "2016-11-03 19:00:00";
```

iCalender.ics:

```
    $icalender_for_outlook_n_osx = 
    'BEGIN:VCALENDAR' . "\r\n" .
    'VERSION:2.0'. "\r\n" .
    'PRODID:-//hacksw/handcal//NONSGML v1.0//EN'.
    'BEGIN:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
    'DTEND:' . date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($endTime))  . "\r\n" .
    'UID:'. uniqid() . "@".$domain . "\r\n". 
    'DTSTAMP:'. time() . "\r\n".
    'LOCATION:' . $location . "\r\n".
    'DESCRIPTION:'. $uri . "\r\n" .
    'URL;VALUE=URI:' . $uri . "\r\n" .
    'SUMMARY:'. $subject . "\r\n" .
    'DTSTART:'. date("Ymd\THis", strtotime($startTime)) . "\r\n" .
    'PRIORITY:5'. "\r\n" .         
    'END:VEVENT'. "\r\n" .
    'END:VCALENDAR'. "\r\n";
```

Outlook or in Mac calendar the start and end time is either showing several hours back or forward, never getting the value which i have embedded. How do you exactly put the PHP timezone and start/date time exactly as above input submission?

Comment: Its because `strtotime()` parses the timestamp as a European date format `d-m-y` when `-` are used. Perhaps its just better to use `date_create_from_format()`

Comment: it created the time correctly as: `20161106T001126Z` but when i added to the calender, inside the calendar the date is ok, but time shows 01:11 ???

Comment: Well, if I execute `echo date("Ymd\THis", strtotime("2016-11-03 18:00:00"));` it gives me `20161103T180000`, which seems to be more correct as your `20161106` where 06 is the wrong day and the time `001126` is 0 hours, 11 minutes and 26 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I strongly believe `strtotime()` should be avoided and create a date time from format.

```
$format = 'Y-m-d H:i:s';
$icalformat = 'Ymd\THis';
$startTime = '2016-11-03 18:00:00';        
$endTime   = '2016-11-03 19:00:00';

echo DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $startTime)->format($icalformat); // 20161103T180000
echo DateTime::createFromFormat($format, $endTime)->format($icalformat); //   20161103T190000
```